# Doing Validation in ActiveRecord for Rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, activerecord

I am in the process of validating in ActiveRecord with rails and I had a question. When you're validating something in customer method can you just use the attribute name flat out or do I have to use the "@" symbol as if its an instance I'm handling? So which of the ways below is correct? Thank you very much I appreciate it!

For example:

```
if(@person.name == "Chris")
end

if(name == "Chris")
```

Comment: Where's the method at? Is the `@person` object defined?  If you're in the person model `@person.name` is probably going to give you an error unless you've specifically set `@person` somewhere.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think I don't understand well your questions, but I would like to help you.
If you are validating into method of Class should be:

```
def self.validateName(name)
  if(name == "Chris")
    something ..
end
```

If you are validating into view

```
if(@person.name == "Chris")
end
```

If the name is comming via params to the controller

```
if(params[:name] == "Chris")
end
```

I hope help you :)